# calling a variable from a function in python error code: NoneType' object has no attribute 'var1'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, maybe this is a bit of a dumb question, but my intention is to call for a variable of a function using another variable, something along this lines:

```
def fun():
    var1 = 100
    var2 = 'asdasd'
    var3= 24+30

x = fun()
print(x.var1)
```

To which I get the error mentioned in the title, is there a way to make something like this work?
btw, working with python 3.9, if that helps.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions on their own don't have this functionality the way you implemented it. However, there are at least 3 ways to achieve what you need (in no particular order):

#### 1. Use scopes

Read: https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/

*@quamrana gives a good TL;DR of this in their answer.*

You can declare a variable in the global scope and have the function change its value.

```py
var1 = 0

def fun():
    global var1
    var1 = 100
    var2 = 'asdasd'
    var3= 24+30

x = fun()
print(var1)
```

#### 2. Create a class (lots of learning involved)

Read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Your variables can be part of a **class**, and you can then use that to instantiate an **object**. Your function (known as a **method** in this case) can then modify those variables (typically called **properties**), and you can access those.

These concepts are the core of a **paradigm** called **object-oriented programming**, which is a concept central to Python.

```py
class Test_class:
    def fun(self):
        self.var1 = 100
        self.var2 = 'asdasd'
        self.var3 = 24+30

test_object = Test_class()
test_object.fun()
print(test_object.var1)
```

#### 3. Return the values

*This is dependent on the concepts of **scopes** from above.*

Functions can **return** values when control is passed back to the context calling them. With Python, you can return multiple values (using a [**data structure**](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) like a **tuple**), and choose which one to index.

```py
def fun():
    var1 = 100
    var2 = 'asdasd'
    var3= 24+30
    return var1, var2, var3

x = fun()
print(x[0])
```

---

*Any **bolded** term in this answer is a Googleable keyword you can use to better understand what I'm saying.*

Answer (score 1):

Given your code:

```py
def fun():
    var1 = 100
    var2 = 'asdasd'
    var3= 24+30

x = fun()
```

Once `fun()` has returned, the names: `var1`, `var2`, `var3` will have disappeared and are no longer accessible.

You can have a modified version which returns three values:

```py
def fun():
    var1 = 100
    var2 = 'asdasd'
    var3= 24+30
    return var1, var2, var3

x = fun()
```

Now at least the values are accessible, but still not by their previous names. Instead you could index into the returned `tuple`:

```py
print(x[1])
```

Output:

`asdasd`

Also, there is another way which is to recreate the names outside the function:

```py
def fun():
    var1 = 100
    var2 = 'asdasd'
    var3= 24+30
    return var1, var2, var3

var1, var2, var3 = fun()
print(var1, var2, var3)
```

Output:

`100 asdasd 54`

Comment: "will have disappeared and are no longer accessible", good explaination of local variables, +1

Comment: oh, i get it, i'm new at this and still get a bit confused on how it works, but that analogy of it disappearing and longer being accessible, really made it click in my head, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

All what you have written will work as expected if instead of a function `foo` was a `class`.

```
class Foo:
    var2 = 40
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 100
print(Foo.var2) # 40
print(Foo().var1) # 100
```

---

In Python, a function (declared with the keyword `def`) doesn't have attributes, and what's more when you do something like this:

```
var = foo()
```

the variable `var` equals the returned value of `foo()`, and not `foo` itself.

Comment: Thanks, with your reply and the other one, i kinda get an idea of how to do what I'm trying to program.